# Sockets in Javascript (Telnet)

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

I have a server that streams data out a telnet connection that I would like to display on a remote webpage. I can acquire the stream from telnet at a remote site but would like to embed the display on a web page as well.

I realize by implementing via Javascript each client will establish its own telnet connection to display the data.

Is there a way to do this?  I tried WebSocket, but it appears it does not support telnet.

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Javascript in browsers can't create raw sockets. You need to do this with a separate server that makes the connection.

Comment: A separate server? I'd still have to get the information from the 2nd server, and I still can't use sockets according to you.

Comment: @bkeahl Javascript can't make sockets, full stop. Only websockets. Your server *can* make sockets because you don't write it in Javascript.

Comment: user253751 is correct of course. I had used Java to get around browser security but that has to be the worst platform to develop in I have ever seen!